# iOS Facebook SDK - How to filter specific category of a page?

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I try to find specific category of user page such as "Clothing" or "Author".
The only way I have is to query whole "me/likes" from Graph API Explorer, such as
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Flikes then try to filter by "category".

But the result might huge if user's page over 100 and need categorize it.
I try to find the FQL but according the FQL table schema, it don't provide a way to filter it because "type" is not a indexible value.
Result: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=SELECT%20name%2C%20about%2C%20description%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20type%20%3D%20'PUBLIC%20FIGURE'

Refer doc: 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page

Any suggestion or thought?